# Writing script creates and calls a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Write a script that creates and calls a stored procedure named test. This stored procedure should
declare a variable and set it to the count of all products in the Products table. If the count is greater
than or equal to 7, the stored procedure should display a message that says, “The number of products
is greater than or equal to 7”. Otherwise, it should say, “The number of products is less than 7”.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE  procedure test()
BEGIN
DECLARE count_of_7 DECIMAL(10,2);

SELECT  count(product_id) 
into count_of_7

FROM products;
IF count_of_7 >= 7 THEN

SELECT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 7' AS message;
ELSE

SELECT 'The number of products is less than 7' AS message;
end if;
call test();
```

21:38:55    CREATE  procedure test() BEGIN DECLARE count_of_7 DECIMAL(10,2) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3    0.016 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter before declaring your procedure. Also, you are missing an `END` statement. This should work:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER //
CREATE  procedure test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE count_of_7 DECIMAL(10,2);

    SELECT count(product_id) into count_of_7 FROM products;
    IF count_of_7 >= 7 THEN
        SELECT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 7' AS message;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'The number of products is less than 7' AS message;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
call test();
```